# response time google spreadsheet with large number of rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm developing a web application that will use a google spreadsheet as a database.
This will mean parsing up to 30.000 (guestimated size) rows in regular operations for searching ID's etc...

I'm worried about the response times i will be looking at. Does anybody have experience with this? I don't want to waste my time on something that will hit a deadend at an issue like that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using spreadsheets as a database for this data set is probably not a good idea. Do you already have this spreadsheet set up?

30K rows will allow you to have only 66 columns, is that enough for you? Check the [Google Docs size limits](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603) help page for more info.

Anyway, Google Spreadsheets have a "live concurrent editing" nature to it that makes it a much slower database than any other option. You should probably consider something else.

Comment: Yes, i've already set it up. Your link was very helpfull. i'll take a look at the fusion tables option(?...). Do you have any suggestions for alternatives which are a relatively good option to intergrate with the app script environment?

I would preferably not want to resort to REST API calls for any external services...

Comment: Oh, you're using Apps Script?! Why don't you you the new [ScriptDb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb) Service?

Answer (score 1):

Do you intend to use the spreadsheet to display data or only as a storage place.?

In this second option the relative slowness of the spreadsheet will not be an issue since you'll only have to read its data once to get its data in an array and play with that...

This implies of course that you build every aspect of data reading and writing in a dedicated UI and never show the spreadsheet itself , the speed will be depending only on the JavaScript engine on arrays, the speed of UI and the speed of your internet connection... all 3 factors being not very performing if compared to a 'normal' application but with the advantage of being easily shareable and available anywhere.:-)

That said, I have written such a database app with about 20 columns of data and 1000 rows and it is perfectly useable although having some latency even for simple next / previous requests. On the other hand the app can send mails and create  docs.... the advantages of Google service integration :-)

You could have a look at t[his example to see what I'm talking about](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxquizfGo85vdeaN7_qss2-LY--UxSLFFeF5ML5rXPWZfrX9oNt/exec)

Comment: I'm extending the spreadsheet and I'm trying to make a call to get the data once and store the content of the spreadsheet in an array. The problem is when I'm using a UI with events and handlers. If the data is passed in callback it's too slow (30 seconds between even and handling of the event), and the data is too large for the ScriptDb and for PropertiesService. So, how can I actually save my data in an array that I can pass into handler functions?